# java desktop app jdialog window with eclipselink jpa. not launching

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans

I designed a java desktop application using eclipselink as the persistence api,I have a jdialog window that shows values inputed to the database because the entitymanager pulls a result list,my problem is ,in the IDE. I can view this jdialog ,but when I clean build it to a. Jar file,it doesn't launch or do anything,please help

Comment: What error do you get?  Enable logging and debug it.

Comment: There are no errors actually,It works fine on the IDE, normally when calling a JDialog,the constructor is new JDialog(new JFrame(),false).setVisible(true); and this popsUp, now this JDialog class. Is trying to read the database values unto a jtextarea,works fine on the ide ,but when clean and built won't popUp,note that in trying to access the values,an entitymanager em ,will be creating a query